# Designing Form with css in javafx

Tags: java, css, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

i am a beginner in javafx and hence designing the form for desktop application in javafx. I am using netbeans. i have gone through some javafx tutorials.

My problem is i am trying to embed my custom css to my javafx code and i am using SceneBuilder with netbeans. Now, the changes or the tags in my css is not reflecting the change in my UI.

For ex: if it is background color- if i use `.login{-fx-background-color: #368ee0;}` in my css it works, but if i write `.login{background-color: #368ee0;}` it does not work. I don't know where am i doing wrong.

Please help and i can provide some part of code or some file for your ref. if required.

Answer (score 1):

`-fx-background-color` is a valid JavaFX attribute, but `background-color` is not (so don't use it).

Only the CSS attributes which are defined in the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) are valid in JavaFX - you can't use CSS attributes designed for HTML such as `background-color`.

Comment: I need to design an interactive java desktop application but the CSS references for javax is not much enhanced. Is there any other way that could help me in designing the UI that could result in Interactive and responsive UI.

Comment: Sorry I can't help further, I do not understand what your comment is saying.  Questions and comments requesting advice choosing libraries or offsite link pointers are [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stack overflow.